# How to Remove All Views from Azure Synapse SQL Serverless Inbuilt

Tags: azure-synapse

Can let me know how to remove views/tables from Azure Synapse Inbuilt SQL Serverless Pool.

Its easy enough to remove individual tables/views using following:

```
use [DatabaseName] 
GO 
drop EXTERNAL table schemaname.tablename
```

But I would to remove all the views/tables shown here:

[image]

Comment: DROP VIEW dbo.[account]

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway, thanks for reaching out. I was hoping you were going to show me how to remove all views with a single query/execution. You have shown me how to remove just one view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following T-SQL query which builds a dynamic SQL statement to drop all views:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (
select STRING_AGG('drop view ['+s.name+'].['+v.name+']; ','
')
from sys.views v
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = v.schema_id
where v.is_ms_shipped = 0
)

exec(@sql)
```